# Homogenous magnetic field properties

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

So I have seen in my uni's notes that if $\vec A = \vec r \times \vec H$ in an homogenous magnetic field then it is $\vec H = \vec \nabla \times \vec A$ , but there is no mathematical or physical explanation about it. Can someone help me?

Comment: 1. Please use MathJax for your formulas the next time you post a question. This time, I have edited them. 2. What have you tried to compute $\vec \nabla \times (\vec r \times \vec H)$ for constant $\vec H$? Show your calculation!

Comment: @Hyperon I've just performed the calculation. The right relation should be the one at the end of my answer below. I didn't write the whole calculations since I'm from the smartphone right now.

Answer (score 1):

When electromagnetic potentials, $\phi$, $\mathbf{a}$ are introduced in Electromagnetism, they're usually defined s.t.

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
  \mathbf{b} & = \nabla \times \mathbf{a} \\
  \mathbf{e} & = - \partial_t \mathbf{a} - \nabla \phi \ .
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Integration should provide the desired relation (replacing $\mathbf{h}$ with $\mathbf{b}$), that should read

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{a} = -\frac{1}{2}  \mathbf{r} \times \mathbf{b} \ , 
\end{equation}

as you can prove it by direct computation of the curl (as an example using Cartesian coordinates).

Comment: yeah i just figured out ! it was really simple at the end of the day i just had to do the calculations

Comment: @Konstantina-Dimitra P. :  Αποδοχή μιας απάντησης ως της βέλτιστης ??? (what about the acceptance of an answer as the best one ???)